# Why Ubuntu 14.04 not Sending Correct Awakening Signal to a Display after sleep?

Tags: 14.04, display, suspend, vga

I have Ubuntu 14.04 which is not waking up a display if left running for the night. 
I must each time restart the PC and after which the PC detects the signal (using VGA).

In the long run, the computer goes to sleep. I wake it up but the display never wakes up although I move cables etc.

It may be also a defect in the display. 
The display is Lenovo 19" [model](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/migr-70940) 4431-HE1.

My graphics card is Nvidia gtx 960.

---

Why is Ubuntu 14.04 not sending correct awakening signal to a display after sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your graphics card?

This is most likely caused by a bug in the open-source driver. Have you tried installing the proprietary drivers? (Dash > Additional Drivers)

[Not to mention you will get way better performance with the proprietary driver]

Comment: So have you tried the proprietary drivers?

Comment: Make sure to use the one listed as "Tested"

Comment: @Masi I find that if I leave Chrome open when I suspend, it wakes up with a bunch of graphical weirdness that goes away when I click anywhere on the dash.